# Error in chart legend highchart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm having problems with the generated caption for the chart using Highcharts, 
In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5rNK6/), the problem this error is generated in the legend of "IE" and "Firefox". 
What causes this error and how to fix

```
   series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox < 2',   45.0],
            ['2 < IE <= 3',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari > 1',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.useHTML) as true, problem will be fixed.

```
dataLabels: {
                useHTML:true,
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5rNK6/1/